# setPersistTempDirectory in Jetty 9.2

Tags: jakarta-ee, jetty, java-7

Do you have to rebuild Jetty 9.2 from source if you want to setPersistTempDirectory to true in Jetty 9.2? Is it not possible to set this property to true in a config file?

We don't have a main method. It's entirely bean based using Spring.

Here's some more info on the issue. These threads: 
[[link one]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629697/how-does-jetty-figures-out-whether-to-expand-a-war-on-start-or-not) and [[link two]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28765187/embedded-jetty-doesnt-clear-temporary-directory-completely-keeps-lib-jar) talks about the same issue.

If you search on the web for

```
WebAppContext.setPersistTempDirectory(true);
or
WebAppContext.setPersistTempDirectory(false);
```

You will see. What I want to accomplish is to make Jetty keep it's previously unpacked temporary .war-folders.

Comment: Please provide some more informations, it's not clear what is your problem. Have a read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

If your Spring environment can manage the `WebAppContext` for your web application, then yes, you can set this value with a call to [`WebAppContext.setPersistTempDirectory(boolean)`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.2.14.v20151106/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext.html#setPersistTempDirectory(boolean))

Comment: Do you mean that if the Spring version is really old, the only option is to rebuild Jetty from source changing this setting from false to true?